# Lagrangian transformation in classical field theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, field-theory, notation, variational-calculus

Let's suppose we have a field $\phi(x)$ whose lagrangian density is denoted with $L[\phi(x), \partial^\mu\phi(x),x]$.

Let's consider a field transformation, usually denoted with $\phi(x)\rightarrow\phi'(x)$. From what I understand this means that the transformation, represented just by the symbol $\rightarrow$ associates to the function $\phi$ of the coordinates $x$ a different function $\phi'$ of the coordinates. To give an example, if $\phi$ is the field defined by $\phi(z)=z^\mu z_\mu+1$, the $\rightarrow$ symbol is a function $T$ that defines $\phi'=T[\phi]$, which may be a completely different field (i.e. a new function of the coordinates), say, $\phi'(z)=(T[\phi])(z)=(z^\mu z_\mu)^2+2$.

Let's consider now a coordinates transformation $x\rightarrow x'$. This means, if I am correct, that we define a function, say, $f$ of the coordinates and denote with $x'$ the value $x'=f(x)$ (where $f$ is a function from $R^4$ to $R^4$).

If my interpretation of the symbol $\rightarrow$ is correct, my questions are two:

1. Often the notation $\phi(x)\rightarrow\phi'(x')$ is used, to denote a transformation which involves, in some way, at the same time a field and coordinates transformation. How this notation has to be intended in terms of the notation I previously used (i.e. using symbols $T$ and $f$)?
2. Which operations should be carried out to transform the lagrangian $L[\phi(x), \partial^\mu\phi(x),x]$ under $\phi(x)\rightarrow\phi'(x')$? Any explicit example would be also useful.

Comment: Coordinate transformations are usually linear and invertible. So not all functions as you defined would be suitable for coordinate transfrormations.

Comment: @flippiefanus Coordinate transformations are generally not linear (for example the map from cartesian to spherical coordinates or vice versa).

Comment: @Andrew, yes you are right. Guess what I'm trying to say is that there are restrictions on the types of functions that can represent coordinate transformation.